# wp_remote_get() returns 403 while file_get_contents() does not

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, rest-api, api

We are working on a WordPress plugin and we require an API call. 
We are using the api: `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=8.8.8.8`

In this context:

```
     $response = wp_remote_get("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={$ip}",  array(
                'timeout'     => 45,
                'redirection' => 5,
                'user-agent'  => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)',
            ));
            $dataArray = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
            var_dump($response);
```

However, all we get is a 403 error saying:

```
string(162) "
403 Forbidden
nginx 
"
```

The API call worked fine using this code:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={$ip}")
```

However, we are only allowed to use `wp_remote_get()` by WordPress.

We have been at this for a while now and we just can't get it fixed or find any solution. We have even tried to give it an user-agent argument to make it look like a browser connected but even that had no success.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thank you for taking your time!

Edit:

An example expected return:

```
{
  "geoplugin_request":"8.8.8.8",
  "geoplugin_status":206,
  "geoplugin_delay":"2ms",
  "geoplugin_credit":"Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href='http:\/\/www.maxmind.com'>http:\/\/www.maxmind.com<\/a>.",
  "geoplugin_city":"",
  "geoplugin_region":"",
  "geoplugin_regionCode":"",
  "geoplugin_regionName":"",
  "geoplugin_areaCode":"",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode":"",
  "geoplugin_countryCode":"US",
  "geoplugin_countryName":"United States",
  "geoplugin_inEU":0,
  "geoplugin_euVATrate":false,
  "geoplugin_continentCode":"NA",
  "geoplugin_continentName":"North America",
  "geoplugin_latitude":"37.751",
  "geoplugin_longitude":"-97.822",
  "geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius":"1000",
  "geoplugin_timezone":"",
  "geoplugin_currencyCode":"USD",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol":"$",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8":"$",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter":1
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem, could you solve it?

Comment: @Rick Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have curly brackets in there?

Maybe sanitize/process the query string with `htmlspecialchars(`) first. The error is complaining about non-standard characters...which is what your curly brackets are doing.

Build the query string with the $ip value, convert with `htmlspecialchars()`, then add the URL to the query string. Pass that variable to the `wp_remote_get()` function.

Comment: It's just out of habit and good practice since it's required in cases of objects or arrays. But even a hard-coded string like the one I gave in the answer  `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=8.8.8.8` for example gives the same 403 forbidden error. :(